# get Object created current Object

Tags: c#, object, parent

Let's assume

```
public abstract class Game
{
    // Base
}

public class Poker : Game
{
    // Lobby Object
    // NUMBER OF PLAYERS ( Max )   ----------
}                                            '
                                             '
public class Lobby                           '
{                                            '
    // List<Tables>                          '
}                                            '
                                             '
public class Table                           '
{                                            '
    // List<Player>                <---------'
}
```

**How** to access **NUMBER OF PLAYERS** from *Table* Object without redundant passing **?**

---

**EDIT I**
You misunderstood my question, I'm sorry.
I want to access the maximum number that can join this Table from its game type.
So if It's a Poker table I want to get NUMBER OF PLAYERS which is equal 10

---

**EDIT II**
Different Game types: Hearts, Spades, Poker, Estimation, ... etc
Max number of players are : 4, 4, 10, 4, etc respectively.

---

**EDIT III**
Again, misunderstood my question,  I want to be able to do the following :

> When player attempt to join a table, I compare target table current
>   players number with its game type max number of players, so I decide
>   if the player can or can't join it !

Comment: So what are the different game types? And their maximum of players?

Comment: So if you have a Poker Table and there are 2 players currently it should return 8 players ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the following relationship needs to be modelled:

```
public abstract class Game
{
    // force all Game descendants to implement the property
    public abstract int MaxPlayers { get; } 
}

public class Poker : Game
{
    // Lobby Object
    public List<Lobby> Lobbies { get; set; }

    // NUMBER OF PLAYERS ( Max )
    // the abstract prop needs to be overridden here
    public override int MaxPlayers 
    { 
       get { return 4; } 
    }
}   

public class Lobby
{
    public List<Table> Tables { get; set; }
}

public class Table                           
{                    
    public Game CurrentGame { get; set; }
    public List<Player> Players { get; set; }

    // force the Game instance to be provided as ctor param.
    public Table(Game gameToStart)
    {
        CurrentGame = gameToStart;
    }
}
```

Inject the `Game` being played when the `Table` is instanced:

```
var pokerGame = new Poker();
// more code here, etc etc

var myTable = new Table(pokerGame);
```

To get the max number of players allowed in a `Table` instance:

```
var maxAllowed = Table.CurrentGame.MaxPlayers;
```

Comment: Yeah, From where the Table object got the CurrentGame object ?

Comment: You should enforce the constructor of `Table` object so that a `Game` instance is provided as constructor param. Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using LINQ to objects you can do this very easily.

```
public abstract class Game
{

}

public class Poker : Game
{
    private Lobby lobby = new Lobby();

    public int MaxPlayers         
    { 
        get
        {           
           int count = lobby.tableList.Sum(t => t.playerList.Sum(c => t.playerList.Count));
           return count;
        }                 
    }


public class Lobby
{
    public List<Table> tableList { get; set; }
}

public class Table
{
    public List<Player> playerList { get; set; }
}

public class Player
{

}
```

Comment: How, I'm now inside Table object which comes from a List in Looby which is an object in the Poker Game !

Comment: It is not fair to downvote I gave the right direction and the code works. So please remove the downvotes!